# Can a discord bot count how many reaction a user got on there profile?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So i wanted to know if a discord bot can count how many reaction a image has and depending on the reactions the user gets it gives them a xp or -xp from there levels kinda like reddits upvote and downvote system

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look on the internet before posting a really long answerable question. For example on a discord.js guide on the reaction page -> [Link](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html)

And yes, discord bot after sending a message can make a message collector where they collect all informations about message reaction (count, users, reaction name and ids)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`messageReactionAdd`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-messageReactionAdd) event, and a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
// create the map (use any name)
const karma = new Map();

// set up the event
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {

  // check if the message has an attachment. you can add any other conditions here as well,
  // such as the channel the message was sent in, etc.
  // (to fetch the message object, use `reaction.message`
  if (!reaction.message.attachments) return;
  
  // you should also create a filter so that this will only trigger for certain reactions (upvotes and downvotes)
  const upvote = '' // for example
  const downvote = '' // for example
  
  if (![upvote, downvote].includes(reaction.emoji.name)) return;

  // check if the map has an entry for this user. if not, make one
  if (!karma.has(user.id)) 
     karma.set(user.id, reaction.emoji.name === upvote ? 1 : -1) // either give the new user 1 or -1 karma depending on the emote
  
  // otherwise, increment/decrement karma total depending on emoji
  else reaction.emoji.name === upvote ? karma.get(user.id)++ : karma.get(user.id)--

});
```

Then, whenever you want to get someone's "karma", you can just use:

```js
karma.get('<ID Here>')
```

Comment: when i try to get the number of upvotes with a simple karma command it just says """[object] also its giving me a error where is says user is not defined

Comment: You can't use the `user` variable outside of the `messageReactionAdd` event, just put in the user ID instead (for example, you could use `message.author.id`, etc.). Also, please provide the line of code that returns `[object Object]`